# Correctly reading a known number of integer inputs into a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new to C++ and wanted to make a small function today which would flip all the elements of an array that was given to it (I had a pretty good idea for it). I started using arrays, but ran into issues since only a pointer to the first element is passed to the function; it was giving some very strange output. It was recommended I use a `vector` instead, but that started to give me some really odd output, too. I added a `cout` iterating over the vector values to see what it contains for some sanity-checking, but the outputs are completely bizarre; looks like I'm struggling to work out how to read input into it correctly.

As I mentioned, I first tried an array, which I could read into fine with a `range-for` loop. I tried that same thing with vectors (solution 1) and found it to be ignoring the first input, and assigning each element the last value that I gave it.

I first tried other Stack overflow threads but I found the solutions far too verbose or not suitable for something as simple as I need.

I thought maybe the vector couldn't be used in the `range-for` so I did `for(auto x : array_size)` instead - this gave an error stating there was no suitable "begin" for the function, so I changed this back.

Instead I looked around at the documentation and found `.push_back(value)` (solution 2) which appeared to put a given value at the end of the vector. Thought I might at least get some input into it correctly, which would be a step in the right direction. Instead, the output seems to show it doubled the number of positions in the vector and just assigned my first input to the furthest position. I imagine this is due to me specifying a size for the vector, and then having `push_back` grow the vector by that number of inputs (resulting in a double-size vector).

As for the input values themselves, I'm stumped.

Below is the offending bit of code as it stands with solution 2.

```
int main()
{
    int array_size;
    auto index_num = 0;
    int arr_input = 0;
    std::cout << "This program flips an array." << "\n";
    std::cout << "Enter how many elements will be in your array: ";
    std::cin >> array_size;

    std::vector<int> user_array (array_size);

    std::cout << "Fill your array with integer values. Press 'Enter' after each: " << std::endl;

    for(auto x : user_array)
        {
            std::cin >> arr_input;
            user_array.push_back(arr_input);
        }

    index_num = sizeof(user_array) / sizeof(user_array[0]);  //or just use array_size-1 instead?

    std::cout << "Your array, unflipped, contains the values: " << "\n";
        for(auto y : user_array)
        {
            std::cout << "[" << user_array[y] << "] ";
        }
```

Solution 2 provides this output:

```
Fill your array with integer values. Press 'Enter' after each:
1
2
3
4
5
Your array, unflipped, contains the values:
[0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [1]
```

Solution 1, where I attempt to input directly into the n-th location of the vector (as I would with an array) provides this output (with the same five 1 - 5 inputs):

```
Your array, unflipped, contains the values:
[0] [5] [5] [5] [5]
```

No error messages, everything is perfectly legal, I clearly just don't understand how something simple like a vector is implemented here.

I haven't even got to the taxing bit yet - flipping the array! Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Whenever you perform a read operation on an input stream, you must check that the read succeeded, and deal with any failure.

Comment: `std::cout << "[" << user_array[y] << "] ";` -> `std::cout << "[" << y << "] ";`. You'll still have more issues but this will get you to the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing `std::vector` with C-style arrays.

---

```
std::vector<int> user_array (array_size);
```

initializes `user_array` with `array_size` zeroes.

```
for(auto x : user_array)
{
    std::cin >> arr_input;
    user_array.push_back(arr_input);
}
```

As noticed by [Alexander Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9254539/alexander-zhang), this piece modifies the vector while iterating over it, which results in Undefined Behaviour. It could result in anything happeining in your program, including infinite loop, crashing completely, supposingly working correct or [demons flying out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

```
index_num = sizeof(user_array) / sizeof(user_array[0]);  //or just use array_size-1 instead?
```

This line makes no sense. You can get the length of vector using its `size()` method: `user_array.size();`, but you don't use that variable anyway.

```
for(auto y : user_array)
{
    std::cout << "[" << user_array[y] << "] ";
}
```

This loop makes no sense either. `y` **is not** an index in the vector, it is a value from that vector. If you have a vector `{10, 20, 30}`, then in first iteration `y` is equal to `10`, in second iteration `y` is `20` and in third `y` is `30`.

---

After fixing the errors, your code should look like this:

```
std::vector<int> user_array ();

std::cout << "Fill your array with integer values. Press 'Enter' after each: " << std::endl;

for(int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> arr_input;
    user_array.push_back(arr_input);
}

std::cout << "Your array, unflipped, contains the values: " << "\n";
for(auto y : user_array)
{
    std::cout << "[" << y << "] ";
}
```

Or for an (invisible) increase in performance, you can reserve the size of the vector before you read it:

```
std::vector<int> user_array ();
user_array.reserve(array_size);

std::cout << "Fill your array with integer values. Press 'Enter' after each: " << std::endl;

for(int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
{
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    user_array.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: For more complex types `push_back` with a `reserve` call first would be faster than your second example because you're default-initializing all the elements and then overwriting those values.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang I think it's too late for StackOverflow for me, thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks for breaking that down so thoroughly for me! 
I was still stuck with what I knew about using arrays, which was causing issues. 

The line for `index_num = ~~~` was a hold-over from that; it was how I planned to pass the size of the array to my function before I added the `array_size` variable. 

Using your advice I have it correctly outputting the values now. Thanks again, and thanks @Alexander Zhang for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<int> user_array (array_size)` creates a vector containing `array_size` zeros. You then use `push_back` which adds additional elements to the end. You need to create an empty vector using `std::vector<int> user_array`, and optionally with a *capacity* of `array_size` by calling `user_array.reserve(array_size)`. Since your vector starts out empty now, you'll need to change `for(auto x : user_array)` to a non-range-based loop such as `for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)`.

`sizeof(user_array) / sizeof(user_array[0])` only works with plain C arrays, not vectors. Use `array_size` or `user_array.size()`.

In the last range-based for loop, `y` is the values in the array, not the indices. So print `y`, not `user_array[y]`.